# How can I clear specific text area if an question is answered in a specific way? (via Google forms to Google docs)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google form which I am running and based on the responses and inputs it's generating a letter automatically. However if possible I would it to be able to clear specific bit of text in the letter if the form selection chooses "none" as a form option.

E.g  for `var auditorAddressLine4 = e.values [5];` if this section in the form the someone was to input "none" I would like it to clear address line 4 from the letter and leave this area blank.

Is this possible?

```js
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {

  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var auditorFirmName = e.values[1];
  var auditorAddressLine1 = e.values[2];
  var auditorAddressLine2 = e.values[3];
  var auditorAddressLine3 = e.values[4];
  var auditorAddressLine4 = e.values[5];
  var dateOfLetterIssue = e.values[6];
  const template = "template";
  
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("");
  var templateFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("");

  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(auditorFirmName + $ {
    template
  }, templateFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{{Insert Auditor Firm name}}", auditorFirmName);
  body.replaceText("{{Address Line 1}}", auditorAddressLine1);
  body.replaceText("{{Address Line 2}}", auditorAddressLine2);
  body.replaceText("{{Address Line 3}}", auditorAddressLine3);
  body.replaceText("{{Address Line 4}}", auditorAddressLine4);
  body.replaceText("{{Date}}", dateOfLetterIssue);

  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see any logic to that effect in your code. There's lots of information to be found on `if()` statements for Google Docs.

Comment: Unfortunately I havent tried anything yet. I wasnt sure how to even go about this. I only managed to write the current code from a youtube tutorial video and support within this channel. 

I have again tried searching what I want online however have been unable to find the questions on here or else where. 

My knowledge level on this google app scripts is very low

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As isherwood was saying in his comment, based on my understanding, a simple `if` statement can solve your issue. Then pair it with `findText` and `deleteText` so you know what to delete in the template. See code below.

#### Code:

```
...
body.replaceText("{{Address Line 3}}", auditorAddressLine3);
if(auditorAddressLine4 == "none") {
  // if "none", remove the string.
  var string = body.findText("{{Address Line 4}}");
  var startOffset = string.getStartOffset();
  var endOffset = string.getEndOffsetInclusive();
  string.getElement().asText().deleteText(startOffset, endOffset);
}
else {
  body.replaceText("{{Address Line 4}}", auditorAddressLine4);
}
body.replaceText("{{Date}}", dateOfLetterIssue);
...
```

In above code, the main idea should be if the value is `"none"` for `auditorAddressLine4`, then the `"{{Address Line 4}}"` will be deleted instead of being replaced by `"none"`.

#### Note:

- You might need to show a sample template and values so it can be properly modified if the answer above won't work.

#### EDIT:

This code below worked on sample

#### Code:

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var formResponse = e.response;
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  var test1 = itemResponses[0].getResponse();  
  var test2 = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
  const template = "template";
  
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("file id");
  var templateFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder id");

  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy("test " + template, templateFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{{TEST 1}}", test1);
  if(test2 == "None") {
    var string = body.findText("{{TEST 2}}");
    var startOffset = string.getStartOffset();
    var endOffset = string.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    string.getElement().asText().deleteText(startOffset, endOffset);
  }
  else {
    body.replaceText("{{TEST 2}}", test2);
  }

  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

#### Test 1:

[image: test1]
[image: output1]

#### Test 2:

[image: test2]
[image: output2]

#### Note:

- Script was added to form so it looked different. But what's important is the `if-else` block.

#### Sheet script:

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var test1 = e.values[1];  
  var test2 = e.values[2];
  const template = "template";
  
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("file id");
  var templateFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder id");

  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy("test " + template, templateFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{{TEST 1}}", test1);
  if(test2 == "None") {
    var string = body.findText("{{TEST 2}}");
    var startOffset = string.getStartOffset();
    var endOffset = string.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    string.getElement().asText().deleteText(startOffset, endOffset);
  }
  else {
    body.replaceText("{{TEST 2}}", test2);
  }

  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Comment: Hey so I have created this as a tester - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zUrELKuybVfG2O6Gw0FkgT1ZET0XkBkw?usp=sharing

On the question in the form named "TEST 2" if someone was to input either TEST A or B as an option I wish for it to replace the text. However if they were to select the option "none" it should clear the text in the doc. 

Hope that makes it clearer sorry if it doesnt

Comment: Hi @ManrajSidhu, I have modified my answer and included some revisions based on your tester. Please check.

Comment: Hey thanks for looking into this, I have tried submitting the form however it is not currently generating the word doc as it should be. I have amended the script slightly however have not touched the bits you have entered. Is there any reason the doc is not being produced on form submit? @NaziA

Comment: Have you tried debugging? was the trigger successfully executed? were the values the expected? @ManrajSidhu

Comment: @ManrajSidhu, on your tester, i placed the script but cannot create a trigger. Create a trigger on form submit in form script. then submit a response. Please do see if it works.

Comment: Hey @NaziA I currently have a trigger running and this error is  being generated on form submits " TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItemResponses' of undefined"

Comment: Also just a quick question I have noticed the script you have written uses "responses" rather than "values". Could this be causing the issue in terms of why the spreadsheet is not triggering the document on submit. Im not sure which parts of your script I can edit to change from responses to values without messing everything up

Comment: @ManrajSidhu, As I was saying in the note at the bottom of my answer. this script is added into the form (form script, not sheet script). if you use sheet, then use `values`. I am using responses as I didn't see the need into using sheet in my case as I was just showing how the `if` statement work. if your script is in the sheet, then change it into using values. the error undefined is caused by `e.response` being null since the property is only present in form event. see [`events`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: @ManrajSidhu, added sheet script at the bottom.

Comment: Hi @ManrajSidhu, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Thanks I can confirm this has worked and hadn't realised the script was for Forms instead of sheets. Thanks for the support @NaziA